# How to resize an image box in a word image mail merge?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a mail merge that someone else made for me that draws an image from a folder. The image will populate within a black dotted perimeter, and there's also a larger blueish "placeholder" box that covers a larger area (cannot be seen from image).

My problem is that I'm not able to resize the black dotted box within the blue larger box- it seems anchored in some way, and I can't see a way to adjust this in its settings.

So if I try to resize from the top anchor point, for example, it will resize by the bottom edge of the shape, because the top edge doesn't want to move.

Does anyone have an idea how I can change this so that I can move and resize this freely?

[image]